# Same directive to multiple inputs. it's possible? AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I hope u can help me.

I have a directive:

```
.directive('checkField', ['$http', function($http) {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, ele, attrs, c) {
            scope.$watch(function() {
                if (attrs.ngModel === 'data.gender_value' && ele.val() !== '') {
                    //valid
                } else {
                    //error
                }

                if (attrs.ngModel === 'data.cardholder_value' && ele.val() !== '') {
                    //valid
                } else {
                    //error
                }
            });
        },
        template: ''
    };
}])
```

And i have multiple inputs in my html:

```
<input ng-model="data.cardholder_value" type="text" size="50" data-check-field />
<input ng-model="data.gender_value" type="text" ng-required="true" data-check-field />
```

The problem is that watch trigger only "see" the first input, no more.

I'm trying to use de same directive to multiple inputs, but doesn't work. If i do an alert, to check the attribute name of field, always display "data.cardholder_value", never other name field.

Thank u in advance.

Edit 1:

This is my html calling (ng-include):

```
<form method="post" id="formQuestion" name="formQuestion" ng-submit="sendForm()" novalidate ng-controller="questionForm">
{{data | json}}
<div class="slide-animate" ng-include="'/templates/default/partials/_fields/1_card_type.html'"></div>
<div class="slide-animate" ng-include="'/templates/default/partials/_fields/2_gender.html'"></div>
```

My app controller:

```
angular.module('app.controllers')
.directive('checkField', ['$http', function($http) {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, ele, attrs, ctrl) {
            scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function(val) {
                console.log(attrs.ngModel, attrs.name, val)
            });
        },
        template: ''
    };
}])
.controller('questionForm', ['$scope', '$http', 'fieldApiService', function ($scope, $http, fieldApiService) {
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you just need it to watch the value of `ng-model` directive attribute, right now you provided the watcher function as your validation function which mean when it sees function as first argument for the watch it will just only look for the return value from that function to determine if watch listener needs to run or not during every digest cycle.

```
      scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function(val) {
            if (!val) {
                //valid
            } else {
                //error
            }
        });
```

Also remember if you want to catch the user entered values you can always use the existing [`$viewChangeListener`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$viewChangeListeners) property on ngmodel, it will avoid reuse of existing internal watcher and no need to explicitly create one.

```
   c.$viewChangeListeners.push(function(){
       console.log('viewChange', ctrl.$viewValue)
    });
```

**Demo**

```js
angular.module('app', []).directive('checkField', ['$http',
  function($http) {
    return {
      require: 'ngModel',
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function(scope, ele, attrs, ctrl) {
        scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function(val) {
          console.log(attrs.ngModel, attrs.name, val)
        });
        ctrl.$viewChangeListeners.push(function(){
           console.log('viewChange', ctrl.$viewValue)
        });
      },
     };
  }
])
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <input ng-model="data.cardholder_value" name="cardholder" type="text" size="50" data-check-field />
  <input ng-model="data.gender_value" name="gender" type="text" ng-required="true" data-check-field />
</div>
```

Comment: Hi PSL, The problem is that my code works only for the first input, the other inputs do not work. So the code that you pass me only shows the value of the first input. Thanks for ur answer.

Comment: @Sommer see my demo, i have both inputs there and look at the `console`, i am logging it there

Comment: @Sommer Did you look at my demo? and do you see both the changes gets logged? press f12 and open the console if you are on windows

Comment: thank you for your help. Checking your code, i see other problem: the inputs are called in ng-include. When i copy and paste my html inputs direct to my form, ur code works cool. But when use ng-include to call the inputs, the directive code doesn't work. Maybe u know what i'm missing?

Comment: ng-include creates a child scope so you need to make sure the bound model is updated properly (ensuring dot rule). can you show how it is structured.

Comment: @Sommer You have a dot rule issue. In your controller define the object on the scope, say `$scope.data = {};` before hand, and then do what you are doing. I cant see what you are doing in your controller though

Comment: thanks, the $scope.data is set in a parent controller. The code {{data | json}} works fine.

Comment: @Sommer Please see my demo in **[plunker with nginclude](http://plnkr.co/edit/8MYK0U?p=preview)** It works just fine, i just initialized data in the controller. If you are still facing the issue please update the plunker and fork it and share the link, i will check. If this answer provided answer to the specific issue please consider accepting the answer.